# Java server socket connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, networking

When my ***SECOND*** client connect to my server I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:200)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:518)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

***FIRST*** client works normal

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50505);;
         Socket socket;
         while (true) {
             socket = serverSocket.accept();
             while(socket.isConnected()) {
                 String v;
                 DataInputStream in;
                 InputStream in_sock;
                 in_sock = socket.getInputStream();
                 in = new DataInputStream(in_sock);
                 v = in.readLine();
                 System.out.println(v);
                 OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(output);
                 out.writeChars("123\n");
                 out.writeChars("123\n");
                 out.writeChars("123\n");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

PS: How can I share error on stackoverflow?  like code?

Comment: Try declaring your `Socket` inside your `while` loop instead of outside it. Although, I don't see how you expect multiple clients to connect simultaneously to a server that's running on a single thread.

Comment: should i use multi threading ? how to use them in with this code ?

Comment: That's too broad of a question for me to answer in a comment, unfortunately. If you want multiple clients to be able to connect simultaneously, you'll need to use multiple threads and/or non-blocking I/O.

Comment: so why u dont answer in answer :D ?

Comment: Because you asked about a specific exception, to which I asked to you to try and declare your `Socket` inside your `while` loop instead of outside it.

Comment: should i make another question ? btw thank you a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If you're still confused on how to properly create a multithreaded server, I first recommend looking online for some examples, as they're everywhere. If you can't get anything to work, then you're free to ask another question. If you don't mind using a networking library, feel free to check out mine: https://github.com/jhg023/SimpleNet

Comment: What do you think [`isConnected()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected--) does? Read the javadocs, it doesn't do what you think it does. Most of those `is*` methods don't do what beginners think they do. They mostly tell you what you already know.

Comment: few moments ago i thought that it checking is client disconnected from the server . I dont check this becouse it didnt showed any errors and code worked

Comment: @JacobG what's the difference of declaring that socket inside of while instead of outside?

Comment: @mangusta Each client would have its own `socket`. Although it doesn’t make much sense here because it’s single-threaded, so only one socket can be active at a time.

Comment: You're declaring things inside the loop that should be declared before it, but the main problem here is that your client isn't closing its socket, hence the reset. Also, you aren't detecting end of stream and you are never closing the socket. `readLine()` returns null at that point, when you should close the socket and cease reading. `isConnected()` is not a valid test for end of stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the big issue, like some other people have said, is that your server can only accept one connection because of the lack of multi-threading.

Right now your server waits for a connection to the port specified

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Then while your socket is still connected you read a line from the socket, print it out to System.out, and then write back to the socket all in a loop. Now this comes into issue because next time a client tries to connect to your serverSocket, it can no longer accept connections because your code is stuck in a loop of reading and writing data from one Socket.

The way to fix this is to introduce multithreading in the way that Milen mentioned above.

Your code should look something like this.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50505);
         while (true) {
             Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
             SocketHandler h = new SocketHandler(socket);
             h.start();
         }
    }
}

public class SocketHandler extends Thread{

    Socket clientSock;
    public SocketHandler(Socket sock){
        clientSock = sock;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(clientSock.isConnected()) {
            String v;
            DataInputStream in;
            InputStream in_sock;
            in_sock = socket.getInputStream();
            in = new DataInputStream(in_sock);
            v = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(v);
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(output);
            out.writeChars("123\n");
            out.writeChars("123\n");
            out.writeChars("123\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code has a loop that accepts connections, and spawns a new thread for every connection!

I would recommend looking at a few things. First, if you check the Java Docs for ServerSocket you will see this constructor

```
ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)
Creates a server socket and binds it to the specified local port number, with the specified backlog.
```

The backlog is the number of incoming connections the server socket can hold onto and store in some sort of buffer until they can be accepted. This is useful if a client is connecting when your accepting loop is in the middle of creating the socket handler. I would recommend putting it at the max number of clients you're expecting.

Secondly, look up the Thread class in the Javadocs. To extend Thread successfully you need to overwrite run(). This method is the method that the thread will execute with. To spawn the thread, you call ThreadObject.start(). You can think of start() as just calling run().

Comment: Your code doesn't compile due to inadequate exception handling; `isConnected()` is not a valid test for end of stream; the streams should be constructed outside the loop; and you've failed to close the socket.

Comment: Yup you're right! I just attempted to adapt their code structure. To accurately check for end of stream, you need to have your while loop check for a null value returned from readline. When that null value is returned, you should close the socket. The exception handling error should be in the I/O part of client handler although there could be more places were exception handling is needed. If you need me to write compilable code, let me know and I'd be happy to do it.

Answer (score 2):

From the "[Writing the Server Side of a Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)" tutorial from Oracle:

> ... the server can service them simultaneously through the use of threads—one thread per each client connection.
>
> The basic flow of logic in such a server is this:
>
> ```
> while (true) {
>     accept a connection;
>     create a thread to deal with the client;
> }
> ```
>
> The thread reads from and writes to the client connection as necessary.

In that tutorial you'll also find links to a server ([KKMultiServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java)) and thread ([KKMultiServerThread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServerThread.java)) sample implementations.